# How to return multiple values in Python map?

Tags: python, functional-programming

I have a list of dicts:

```
>>> adict = {'name': 'John Doe', 'age': 18}
>>> bdict = {'name': 'Jane Doe', 'age': 20}
>>> l = []
>>> l.append(adict)
>>> l.append(bdict)
>>> l
[{'age': 18, 'name': 'John Doe'}, {'age': 20, 'name': 'Jane Doe'}]
```

Now I want to split up the values of each dict per key. Currently, this is how I do that:

```
>>> for i in l:
...     name_vals.append(i['name'])
...     age_vals.append(i['age'])
...
>>> name_vals
['John Doe', 'Jane Doe']
>>> age_vals
[18, 20]
```

Is it possible to achieve this via map? So that I don't have to call map multiple times, but just once?

```
name_vals, age_vals = map(lambda ....)
```

Comment: What if keys are missing in the dictionaries?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Set the corresponding value to `None`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple & flexible way to do this is to "transpose" your list of dicts into a dict of lists. IMHO, this is easier to work with than creating a bunch of separate lists.

```
lst = [{'age': 18, 'name': 'John Doe'}, {'age': 20, 'name': 'Jane Doe'}]
out = {}
for d in lst:
    for k, v in d.items():
        out.setdefault(k, []).append(v)

print(out)
```

**output**

```
{'age': [18, 20], 'name': ['John Doe', 'Jane Doe']}
```

---

But if you really want to use `map` and separate lists on this there are several options. Willem has shown one way. Here's another.

```
from operator import itemgetter

lst = [{'age': 18, 'name': 'John Doe'}, {'age': 20, 'name': 'Jane Doe'}]
keys = 'age', 'name'
age_lst, name_lst = [list(map(itemgetter(k), lst)) for k in keys]
print(age_lst, name_lst)
```

**output**

```
[18, 20] ['John Doe', 'Jane Doe']
```

If you're using Python 2, then the `list` wrapper around the `map` call isn't necessary, but it's a good idea to use it to make your code compatible with Python 3.

Answer (score 6):

If *all* dictionaries have the `'name'` and `'age'` key, and we can use the `zip` builtin, we can do this with:

```
from operator import itemgetter

names, ages = zip(*map(itemgetter('name', 'age'), l))
```

This will produce *tuples*:

```
>>> names
('John Doe', 'Jane Doe')
>>> ages
(18, 20)
```

In case you need lists, an additional `map(list, ..)` is necessary.

Comment: Nice, and it only calls `map` once, as requested.

Comment: question: is this truly equivalent to the for-loop, in that it does only one "pass"? Or is it like `names = [x['name'] for x in l]; ages = [x['age'] for x in l]`, since splatting into `zip` does an iteration (and creates an auxiliary tuple!), then unpacking into `names, ages` is another iteration...?